# Logging count of DELETED records

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

When I try to run this

```
DECLARE @by varchar(20) = 'Myself'

INSERT INTO dbo.MiscLog(LogType, onTable, Message, CreateBy)
   SELECT 
      'Info', 'dbo.History', 
      'There are ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), COUNT(ID)) + ' old records being purged.', @by
   FROM 
       (DELETE FROM dbo.History
        OUTPUT deleted.ID
        WHERE keyDate < dateadd(y, -7, getDate())) H
```

I get

> Msg 5322, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   An aggregate function is not allowed in the SELECT clause when the FROM clause contains a nested INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or MERGE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting a copy of the deleted records into a temp table and then run your COUNT() aggregation on the temp table.

```
SELECT *
INTO #tempLog
   FROM 
       (DELETE FROM dbo.History
        OUTPUT deleted.ID
        WHERE keyDate < dateadd(y, -7, getDate())) H

INSERT INTO dbo.MiscLog(LogType, onTable, Message, CreateBy)
   SELECT 
      'Info', 'dbo.History', 
      'There are ' + CONVERT(varchar(20), COUNT(ID)) + ' old records being purged.', @by
FROM #tempLog
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an `AFTER DELETE` trigger on the table. You can query `deleted` for the count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   deleted
```